# Python vs. MATLAB computing an integral to infinity with different results, alternative (i.e. expand Gauss-Legendre quadrature to -x-> Infinity)?

Tags: python, matlab, cython, numerical-integration, quad

I am getting inconsistent results between MATLAB's `quadgk` and Python's `quad` routine for an integral from (-x or 0) -> infinity.  I believe the MATLAB version is correct (based on a sense check of switching the `flag` parameter from 1 to -1) whereas the Python version gives erroneous results, in this case 0.  MATLAB produces 0.1022. The `integrands` are identical and I have tied out each step of the way, even inserting the `x` values generated by MATLAB's `quadgk` into Python (which results in the Python version generating the same value as MATLAB, just passing them to the `integrand` function).  At this point I'm looking to use another routine rather than SciPy such as Gauss-Legendre quadrature here https://sourceforge.net/projects/fastgausslegendrequadrature/ but I am not sure how to extend it from its a/b range into -a->infinity (I've seen these methods that only go to a finite number:

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/a/7/f/]
[Different intervals for Gauss-Legendre quadrature in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457880/different-intervals-for-gauss-legendre-quadrature-in-numpy) whereas `b=np.Inf` results in `NaN`.   Also not sure how to setup the integration from the returned nodes and weights, although I've been reading the transformation but only for a and b finite ranges: https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/legendre-gauss.html Either that or if someone knows a Python library that can handle this - I don't really like the fact `quad` isn't vectorized though and will likely write the code in Cython, as I have to integrate 600,000 functions quickly (i.e. link to the C++ library link above).  What's really odd here is that I've managed to get identical results by moving up the `vol` input anywhere >= 0.39, below that Python's results collapse at 0.  Very confusing.  Any help is appreciated, it has been years since Calculus... here is the Python code:

```
from scipy.stats import norm, lognorm
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np

def integrand(x, flag, F, K, vol, T2, T1):
    d1 = (np.log(x / (x+K)) + 0.5 * (vol**2) * (T2-T1)) / (vol * np.sqrt(T2 - T1))
    d2 = d1 - vol*np.sqrt(T2 - T1)
    mu = np.log(F) - 0.5 *vol **2 * T1
    sigma = vol * np.sqrt(T1)
    value = lognorm.pdf(x, scale=np.exp(mu), s=sigma) * (flag * x*norm.cdf(flag * d1) - flag * (x+K)*norm.cdf(flag * d2))
    return value

if __name__ == '__main__':
        flag = 1
        F = 54.31
        K = 1.1967
        vol = 0.1328
        T2 = 0.0411
        T1 = 0.0137
        quad(integrand, 0, np.Inf, args=(flag, F, K, vol, T2, T1), epsabs=1e-12)[0]
```

And here is the MATLAB code (have to save the `integrand` as a .M then can enter the script in a command window):

```
function value = integrand(x, flag, F,K,vol,T2,T1)
d1 = (log(x ./ (x+K)) + 0.5 .* (vol.^2) .* (T2-T1)) ./ (vol .* sqrt(T2 - T1));
d2 = d1 - vol.*sqrt(T2 - T1);
mu = log(F) - 0.5 .*vol .^2 .* T1;
sigma = vol .* sqrt(T1);
value = lognpdf(x, mu, sigma) .* (flag .* x.*normcdf(flag .* d1) - flag .* (x+K).*normcdf(flag .* d2));
end
```

% script part

```
flag = 1
F = 54.31
K = 1.1967
vol = 0.1328
T2 = 0.0411
T1 = 0.0137
quadgk(@(x) integrand(x,flag, F, K, vol, T2, T1), 0, Inf, 'AbsTol',1e-12)
```

I should note that MATLAB and Python generate the same results using quad when these inputs are passed instead (transposed above variables):

```
 current_opt = [  -1.0000    1.2075    0.1251    0.4300    0.0685    0.0411     
                1.0000    1.2075    0.0512    0.5600    0.0685    0.0411]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is interesting.  The integration falls apart unless the `epsabs` variable is set ridiculously high. I have managed to replicate results between MATLAB and Python using `epsabs=-1e1000`.  Slow as can be but at least it works.