# Gauss-Legendre over intervals -x -> infinity: adaptive algorithm to transform weights and nodes efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, wolfram-mathematica, numerical-integration

Okay I know this has been asked before with a limited example for scaling `[-1, 1]` intervals `[a, b]` [Different intervals for Gauss-Legendre quadrature in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457880/different-intervals-for-gauss-legendre-quadrature-in-numpy) BUT no one has posted how to generalize this for `[-a, Infinity]` (as is done below, but not (yet) fast).  Also this shows how to call a complex function (in quantitative option pricing anyhow) with several implementations.  There is the benchmark `quad` code, followed by `leggauss`, with links to code examples on how to implement an adaptive algorithm.  I have worked through most of the linked `adaptive algorithm` difficulties - it currently prints the sum of the divided integral to show it works correctly.   Here you will find functions to convert a range from `[-1, 1]` to `[0, 1]` to `[a, Infinity]` (thanks @AlexisClarembeau).  To use the adaptive algorithm I had to create another function to convert from `[-1, 1]` to `[a, b]` which is fed back into the `[a, Infinity]` function.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm, lognorm
from scipy.integrate import quad

a = 0
degrees = 50

flag=-1.0000
F = 1.2075
K = 0.1251
vol = 0.43
T2 = 0.0411
T1 = 0.0047

def integrand(x, flag, F, K, vol, T2, T1):
    d1 = (np.log(x / (x+K)) + 0.5 * (vol**2) * (T2-T1)) / (vol * np.sqrt(T2 - T1))
    d2 = d1 - vol*np.sqrt(T2 - T1)
    mu = np.log(F) - 0.5 *vol **2 * T1
    sigma = vol * np.sqrt(T1)
    return lognorm.pdf(x, mu, sigma) * (flag * x*norm.cdf(flag * d1) - flag * (x+K)*norm.cdf(flag * d2))

def transform_integral_0_1_to_Infinity(x, a): 
    return integrand(a+(x/(1-x)), flag, F, K, vol, T2, T1) *(1/(1-x)**2); 

def transform_integral_negative1_1_to_0_1(x, a): 
    return 0.5 * transform_integral_0_1_to_Infinity((x+1)/2, a)

def transform_integral_negative1_1_to_a_b(x, w, a, b):
    return np.sum(w*(0.5 * transform_integral_0_1_to_Infinity(((x+1)/2*(b-a)+a), a)))

def adaptive_integration(x, w, a=-1, b=1, lastsplit=False, precision=1e-10):
    #split the integral in half assuming [-1, 1] range
    midpoint = (a+b)/2
    interval1 = transform_integral_negative1_1_to_a_b(x, w, a, midpoint)
    interval2 = transform_integral_negative1_1_to_a_b(x, w, midpoint, b)
    return interval1+interval2 #just shows this is correct for splitting the interval

def integrate(x, w, a): 
    return np.sum(w*transform_integral_negative1_1_to_0_1(x, a))

x, w = np.polynomial.legendre.leggauss(degrees) 
quadresult = quad(integrand, a, np.Inf, args=(flag, F, K, vol, T2, T1), epsabs=1e-1000)[0]
GL = integrate(x, w, a)
print("Adaptive Sum Result:")
print(adaptive_integration(x, w))
print("GL result"); 
print(GL)
print("QUAD result")
print(quadresult)
```

Still need to increase the speed and accuracy with less dimensions as I can't manually adjust the `degrees` range for `-a` to get convergence.  To illustrate why this is a problem, put in these values instead: `a=-20`, `F=50`, then run.  You can increase `degrees=1000` and see that there is no benefit to this Gauss-Legendre algorithm if it is not applied intelligently.  My requirement for speed is to get to 0.0004s per loop, whereas the last algorithm I Cythonized took about 0.75s, which is why I am trying to use a low degree, high accuracy algorithm with Gauss-Legendre.  With Cython and multi-threading this requirement from a completely optimized Python implementation is roughly 0.007s per loop (a non-vectorized, loop ridden, inefficient routine could be 0.1s per loop, with `degrees=20`, i.e. `%timeit adaptive_integration(x,w)`.

A possible solution which I've half implemented is here http://online.sfsu.edu/meredith/Numerical_Analysis/improper_integrals on pages 5/6, `adaptive integration` whereas the interval `a-b` (in this case, I wrote the `transform_integral_negative1_1_to_a_b` function) where the interval is divided in 2 (@`0.5`), the function is then evaluated on these 1/2 intervals, and the sum of the two `0->0.5` + `0.5->1` are compared to the function results for the whole range `0->1`.  If accuracy is not within tolerance, the range is further subdivided at `0.25` and `0.75`, the function is again evaluated for each subinterval, and compared to the prior 1/2 interval sums @`0.5`.  If 1 side is within tolerance (e.g. `abs(0->0.5 - (0->0.25 + 0.25->0.5)) < precision`), but the other side is not, splitting stops on the side within tolerance, but continues on the other side until `precision` is reached.  At this point the results for each slice of the interval are summed to obtain the full integral with higher accuracy.

There are likely faster and better ways of approaching this problem.  I don't care as long as it is fast and accurate.  Here is the best description of integration routines I've come across for reference http://orion.math.iastate.edu/keinert/computation_notes/chapter5.pdf Award is 100pts bounty + 15pts for answer acceptance.  Thank you for assisting in making this code FAST and ACCURATE!

EDIT:

Here is my change to the `adaptive_integration` code - if someone can make this work fast I can accept an answer and award bounty.  This Mathematica code on page 7 http://online.sfsu.edu/meredith/Numerical_Analysis/improper_integrals does the routine I attempted.  It has work on a routine that doesn't converge well, see the variables below.  Right now my code errors out: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison` on some inputs, or if the `degrees` are set too high, or doesn't get close to the `quad` result when it does work, so something is apparently wrong here.

```
def adaptive_integration(x, w, a, b, integralA2B, remainingIterations, firstIteration, precision=1e-9):
    #split the integral in half assuming [-1, 1] range
    if remainingIterations == 0:
        print('Adaptive integration failed on the interval',a,'->',b)
    if np.isnan(integralA2B): return np.nan

    midpoint = (a+b)/2
    interval1 = transform_integral_negative1_1_to_a_b(x, w, a, midpoint)
    interval2 = transform_integral_negative1_1_to_a_b(x, w, midpoint, b)
    if np.abs(integralA2B - (interval1 + interval2))  < precision : 
        return(interval1 + interval2)       
    else:
        return adaptive_integration(x, w, a, midpoint, interval1, (remainingIterations-1), False) + adaptive_integration(x, w, midpoint, b, interval2, (remainingIterations-1), False) 

#This example doesn't converge to Quad

# non-converging interval inputs
a = 0 # AND a = -250
degrees = 10

flag= 1
F = 50
K = 0.1251
vol = 0.43
T2 = 0.0411
T1 = 0.0047

print(adaptive_integration(x, w, -1, 1, GL, 500, False))
```

The output with `degrees=100` (after calculating `GL` with `degrees=10000` for a better initial estimate, otherwise, the algorithm always agrees with its own accuracy apparently and doesn't invoke the adaptive path which fails every time):

```
GL result:
60.065205169286379
Adaptive Sum Result:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
QUAD result:
68.72069173210338
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that code does the job:

```py
import numpy as np 
import math

deg = 10
x, w = np.polynomial.legendre.leggauss(deg)

def function(x): 
    # the function to integrate
    return math.exp(-x)

def function2(x, a): 
    return function(a+x/(1-x))/((1-x)**2); 

def anotherOne(x, a): 
    return 0.5 * function2(x/2 + 1/2, a)

def integrate(deg, a): 
    sum = 0 
    x, w = np.polynomial.legendre.leggauss(deg)
    for i in range(deg): 
        print("sum({}) += {} * {} (eval in {})".format(sum, w[i], anotherOne(x[i], a), x[i]))
        sum += w[i]*anotherOne(x[i], a)
    return sum; 

print("result"); 
print(integrate(10, 1))
```

It combines your equation to integrate from a to inf and the equation to change the bounds of an integral.

I hope it solves your problem (it works for exp(-x) at least) :)

If you want an inline computation, the program does the sum of: 
[image]

It's a combination of:

[image]

And:

[image]

And:

[image]

Comment: The difference seems to be caused by numeric approximation. If you set epsilon absolute value to 10^-10 in the quad method, you will have a very different result. Because the two methods are very different (and we don't know what data structure is used by quad) the way they handle numerical error can be very different :)

To solve the problem you should handle variable precision arithmethic and numerical errors in the gauss-legendre method. (Default python floats have like 10^{-15} precision)

Comment: Hmm; the error seems to be from the formula of bounds swapping from a, inf to 0, 1. 

Matlab shows: 
`quad(@(x) exp(-x), 2, inf) = 0.13534`
`quad(@(x) exp(-(2+x/(1-x)))/(x)^2, 0, 1) = 0.0055822`

So, the two values doesn't match. 
Are you sure of the formula?

Comment: My bad. You must replace the function2 code by: 
`return integrand((a+x/(1-x)), flag, F, K, vol, T2, T1)/((1-x)**2); `
And it will work. 
(/(1-x)^2) is after applying the function ;)

Comment: Works great for all positive values of `a` now, thanks!  But try setting a at `-20` and they diverge.  Is that another equation?

Comment: You just need to increase degree. For 500, it converges. Quad implements (I think) a better algorithm :)

Comment: I'm going to try to apply your answer to a C++ library to use very high `degrees` and see if that works along the ranges of inputs I expect as no one on SO seems to know how to fix the adaptive algorithm...

Answer (score 2):

In "Numerical Programming: A Practical Guide for Scientists and Engineers Using Python and C/C++" by Titus A. Beu, you can find the methods in the code samples `integral.py` and `specfunc.py` here: http://phys.ubbcluj.ro/~tbeu/INP/libraries.html You call the function `xGaussLag(a, deg)` which calls `Laguerre` from the other .py file and returns your adjusted `(x,w)` between `a` and `infinity`.  Here's how to set this up (note just above `deg=80` it is very slow, I'm just showing you how to apply it by modifying lines above):

```
x, w = np.array(xGaussLag(a,deg))
gauss = sum(w * integrand(x, flag, F, K, vol, T2, T1))
```

Gets pretty close convergence on `deg=80` (faster) but I just put the `eps=1e-13` in `xGaussLag` and pushed the `deg=150` with these results, nonetheless faster than `quad` by 33%:

The QUADPACK solution: 0.149221620346 with error: 1.49870924498e-12
Gauss-Legendre solution: 0.149238273747
Difference between QUADPACK and Gauss-Legendre:  1.66534003601e-05

In Cython this is 6x faster than straight Python BTW still too slow so I'm going to try the "FastGL" package with the answer from @Alexis for now, just posting as I think this will be useful for other SO users in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Integrals that stretch over an infinite domain should always raise your suspicion. After all, most "simple" functions can't even be integrated there! That's why one usually has a damping term like `exp(-x)` or `exp(-x**2)` in there. And sure enough, for those two cases you have specific integration rules:

- [Gauss-Laguerre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Laguerre_quadrature) for `exp(-x)` and
- [Gauss-Hermite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Hermite_quadrature) for `exp(-x**2)`.

So instead of trying to transform your integrals into a finite domain, you should try to transform them into either of

[image]

[image]

This can usually be done by hand.